# Автозапуск всех контейнеров в docker

Tags: linux, docker

Имеется докер с несколькими контейнерами. 
После ребута (или отключение электричества) хоста докер не стартует контейнеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/host_integration/) - это не баг, а фича. Запустить руками можно коммандой `docker start -a`. Если надо, чтобы оно само - создать правило в системе инициализации хостовой ОС.

**Upstart**:

```
description "Redis container"
author "Me"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
/usr/bin/docker start -a redis_server
end script
```

**Systemd**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start -a redis_server
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 redis_server

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

Ну или можно `docker start -a` прописать в `/etc/rc.local` - но это за гранью добра и зла.

Comment: Данные директивы необходимо ввести в /etc/systemd/system.conf ?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart), контейнеру можно при создании задать **политику перезапуска** параметром `--restart`, и демон Docker будет при определённых условиях перезапускать контейнеры сам.

- `no` не перезапускает, **по умолчанию**
- `on-failure` и `on-failure:N` перезапускает контейнер, если его процесс завершается с ошибкой (код возврата не 0), максимум `N` раз (или постоянно)
- `unless-stopped` запускает контейнер при старте демона Docker, если контейнер был активен (не был `stop`нут ранее)
- `always` перезапускает всегда, был ли он ранее остановлен или упал

Но это не особо поможет, если контейнер должен быть запущен только когда некая служба будет запущена на хост-системе. В этом случае за порядком должен следить процесс, который об этой службе знает.